# Can I specify any generic enum as a type for a struct field?

Tags: rust, enums

I am providing an interface to manage permissions on different databases. I have an `Apply` trait that different databases can implement to grant a `Permission`:

```rust
pub trait Apply {
    fn apply(&self, permission: Permission) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>;
}
```

`object_type` is a `String`, but I would prefer if each database implementation offered its own custom enum. For example, a Postgres database might have `Database, Schema, Sequences` and so on. A Snowflake database might have `Account, Database, File Format` etc.

```rust
pub struct Permission {
    pub object: String,
    pub object_type: String,
    pub grantee: String,
    pub privileges: Vec<String>,
}
```

Is it possible to have `object_type` be a generic enum (if there is such a thing?) rather than a specific enum?

Comment: Why would to want to restrict it to only an enum? Make it any type, whether struct or enum. `struct Permission<E> { object: String, object_type: E }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking if you can use a generic type, the answer is yes, although you need to understand how generics work and what they entail.

Let's do a simple exercise:

```
pub struct Permission<T> {
    pub object_type: T,
    // ...
}
```

Here we are saying that the `Permission` struct receives a generic type parameter, and use that type on the `object_type` field. This gives us a lot of flexibility, which means that now we can create different instances of `Permission`, such as your first example with a `String`:

```
let permission_with_string_as_object_type = Permission::<String>... // You construct the instance
```

Or with an enum:

```
enum MyDatabaseEnum {
...
}

let permission_with_my_database_enum_as_object_type = Permission::<MyDatabaseEnum> ... // You construct the instance
```

You can also put bounds on the generic type parameter if you want, which can further help describe exactly what you expect from that generic type.

Comment: Ah this is perfect. The bounds specify the contract I need the Generic Type to implement, and I can leave it up to each adapter to decide what type they wish to use, so long as it meets the bounds? Rust is so great!

Comment: @pedram Yes, that pretty much sums it up I think :) You got it

Comment: It's more idiomatic to omit the explicit type parameter entirely and just let the compiler infer it.